# view pager not displaing image

Tags: android, android-fragments

here is my grid view ,it is pass position to view pager class by using intent...`

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int pos = 0;
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) m1Context)
                .getLayoutInflater();
        View customRow1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gview, null);
        ImageView image = (ImageView) customRow1
                .findViewById(R.id.imageforgrid);
        switch (gotbread) {
        case 0:

            image.setImageResource(images2[pos]);
            break;
        case 1:
            image.setImageResource(images1[position]);
            break;
        }
        image.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
        image.setScaleX((float) 0.5);
        image.setScaleY((float) 0.5);
        image.setOnClickListener(new OnImageClickListener(position));
        return customRow1;
    }
}

class OnImageClickListener implements OnClickListener {

    int _postion;

    // constructor
    public OnImageClickListener(int position) {
        this._postion = position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // on selecting grid view image
        // launch full screen activity
        Bundle basket=new Bundle();
        basket.putInt("position",_postion);
        Intent i = new Intent(Customgrid.this,
                FullScreenImageActivity.class);
        i.putExtras(basket);
        startActivity(i);
    }

}
```

}

`

here is view pager for showing image in swip view ...but it's not display image in full screen view ..it not showing any error but it coming just black screen with out any image.

```
public class FullScreenImageActivity extends Activity {

int gotbiscuit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fullscreen_view);
    ViewPager viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    Intent i = getIntent();
    int gotbiscuit = i.getExtras().getInt("position");
     System.out.print(gotbiscuit);
    Fullscreenimage adapter = new Fullscreenimage(
            FullScreenImageActivity.this);

    viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);

    // displaying selected image first
    viewpager.setCurrentItem(gotbiscuit);
}

public class Fullscreenimage extends PagerAdapter {
    public Integer[] images1 = { R.drawable.s_1, R.drawable.s_2, R.drawable.s_3 };

    public Context mContext;


    public Fullscreenimage(Context context) {
        super();
        this.mContext = context;

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return images1.length;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
        View viewlayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_fullscreen_view,
                container, false);
        ImageView imageview = (ImageView) viewlayout
                .findViewById(R.id.imgDisplay);
        imageview.setImageResource(images1[gotbiscuit]);
        ((ViewPager) container).addView(viewlayout, 0);
        return viewlayout;

    }
}
```

}